# AWS RDS: New master password doesn't set

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to connect to RDS and I found out I didn't set the master password for my instance.
So I set the new password and tell it to set it immediately but seems like the new password doesn't set.
The current value doesn't show up on summary of modification. Is this normal thing? How can I check if the new password does set?

Comment: Do you see (**********) on the password field in the summary of modification?

Comment: I see **** on the new password's section but the current value's section is always empty.

Comment: I think this is the normal behaviour to see an empty value even if the Master password has been set properly. In my case it's also empty but it worked.

Comment: Okay I got it. Thanks.